# ¿Cómo cargar un diccionario desde una archivo de texto en Python?

Tags: python, diccionarios, txt

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
data={'1':'0800',
'2':'0810',
'3':'0820',
'4':'0830',
'5':'0840',
'6':'0850',
'7':'0900',
'8':'0910',
'10':'0920',
'12':'0940',
'13':'0950',
'14':'1000',
'15':'1010',
'16':'1020',
'17':'1030',
'18':'1040',
'19':'1050',
'20':'1100',
'21':'1110',}

for key, value in data.items():
    print ("key")
    print ("value")
```

Tengo ese diccionario guardado en un archivo .txt y quisiera abrirlo directamente desde allí, en vez de escribir todo esos valores en el código.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Agrega el archivo de texto con el diccionario. Es un detalle importante.

Answer (score 1):

La recolección de información a través de un archivo de texto plano puede ser de maneras muy distintas, la manera más sencilla para tu ejemplo seria simplemente utilizar una estructura en el archivo como la siguiente:

```py
# archivo data.txt

llave1: valor1
llave2: valor2
llave3: valor3
.....
.....
```

Que finalmente podría ser leído mediante python con:

```py
with open('data.txt', 'r') as archivo:
    separador = ':'
    data = {}
    
    for linea in archivo:
        key, value = linea.split(separador)
        data[key.strip()] = value.strip()

    print(data)
```

Realmente el programa lo único que hace es la apertura del archivo en modo lectura, navega por cada línea del archivo y a cada línea la parte en dos, esta partición es hecha a partir de la cadena `separador` que simplemente es `:`. Finalmente la primera parte de esa partición es considerada la llave y la segunda el valor, el método [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) permite eliminar los espacios en blanco que se encuentren al inicio y final de la cadena.

Una versión mas portable seria utilizar un formato bien establecido como [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) que simplificaría aún más la implementación.

```
# archivo data.json
{
  "clave1":"valor1",
  "clave2":"valor2",
  "clave3":"valor3",
  "clave4":"valor4"
}
```

Lectura desde python:

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

En ambos casos debes tener en consideración los tipos, en el primer ejemplo la lectura siempre va traer los valores como tipo cadena aún cuando estos intenten representar números, la conversión debe correr por tu cuenta para corregir esos posibles problemas. En el caso de JSON, el formato específica que para diferenciar los valores que representan números estos no deben estar rodeados entre comillas, si respetas esos estandares, la conversión sera automática.